# Which parts of this U.FL laptop wifi antenna need to be exposed?

Tags: antenna, wifi, shielding, laptop

I got these wifi antennas for use in a small metal computer case. I'm cutting some holes in the case to give the antennas exposure, but I'm not sure what parts of the antenna need to be exposed. As you can see, there is a circuit board portion, and a "flap" portion. Do both of these need to be exposed, or can one or the other be inside the metal case? Thank you!
[image: Front side of antennas]

[image: Back side of antennas]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, to get the best performance from such an antenna, there should be **no metal whatsoever** in the vicinity of the antenna. If you keep any metal further away than, say 10 cm (a guess I sucked out of my thumb!), the antenna's radiation pattern should not be that much affected. This type of antenna that you show radiates in all directions more or less equally.

Metal **reflects** the signal that the antenna is radiating. If there is metal too close it blocks the signal in that direction but also the signal can **reflect back** into the antenna preventing it from "getting out"!

So when you're using a metal case/housing and are not using external antennas then you will have to accept a compromised antenna performance. This type of antenna isn't designed to be used near a metal surface.

If you have no alternative then my choice would be to make a hole in the metal case through which the cable and connector can fit. Then keep the PCB outside the case, the cable can be inside, that is no issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Bimpelrekkie ! So PCB outside, cable inside ... what about that flap portion? I can't tell if that's part of the antenna or just something to help attach it to something else. Also, do you happen to know what kind of small wifi antenna _can_ be used near metal surfaces? Again, thank you.

Comment: *what about that flap portion?* The white flap looks to me like a sticker to attach it to something else. I do not think it is part of the antenna. In my opinion the best solution for an antenna near a metal surface would be the "stick" type of antenna like: https://www.banggood.com/2_4GHz-5dBi-Wireless-Wifi-Antenna-Booster-WLAN-RP-SMA-p-940255.html  Yes, it will "stick out" a lot but that helps to get the radio waves in and out. You *can* use all antennas near a metal surface but their performance will suffer as a result. It is not that it will not work, it will work but not that well.